# Getting Error when integrate css file in a layout RAILS 5.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

i'm developping in rails 5.1.1 everything seems alright, i really don't get it why i get this error (i'm new to ror) my app structure is like this :

**application.css** (assests/stylesheets/)

```
 *= require_self
 *= require public
 *= require admin
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

**admin.css** (assests/stylesheets/)

```
 /* just for testing purposes*/
 body{
  background-color: red;
 }
```

**admin.html.erb** (views/layouts/)

```
...
<head>
<title><%= @page_title || "Admin" %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('application', :media => 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true) %>
</head>
...
```

**pages_controller.rb** (controllers)

class PagesController < ApplicationController

```
 layout "admin"
 ...
```

---

I get the error in

> stylesheet_link_tag('**application**')

by displaying **ExecJS::RuntimeError**

Comment: Are you missing the `/*` starting the comment in `application.rb`? Otherwise check the error message for which of your assets is failing to compile or add the stack trace to the question

Comment: @max , thanks for your answer, my application.css start with /*